# ggplot2 colors association problem with ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement, ggplot2, colors, time-series

Here my df structure

```
Date VAR  Value
    1    A    0.1 
    2    A    0.1 
    2    B1   0.2 
    2    B2   0.3 
    2    B3   0.2 
    3    A    0.1
    4    A    0.1
    5    A    0.1
    5    B4   0.4
```

I can plot them. But I have a problem. I want to have for every B only one colour. I cannot write them handly because I have many columns. So I need the grepl function.
I tried like this. But it works wrong.

```
print(ggplot(df, aes(date,value)) 
      + geom_line(aes(colour = ifelse(grepl("B", VAR) == T, "green", "blue")))
```

How can I deal with that?

Comment: I am sorry, it didn't work. I found the solution yesterday. I had to use fill and color together.

print(ggplot(df, aes(date,value, fill = variable, color = colors)) 
        + geom_line()

Answer (score 1):

Create a new column with colors and use `scale_color_identity` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  mutate(color = ifelse(grepl("B", VAR), "green", "blue")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, Value, color = color)) + geom_line() + 
  scale_color_identity()
```

[image]